# Verifying that inputs are in range

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, validation

I'm having a problem implementing this.. the program is meant to take date input in the format `dd.mm.yyyy`, it does that already but I've been trying to add the code that checks

- if the date is more than 31 or February is more than 28
- if the month is more than 12
  It should return an error since the input is incorrect

And also if a user start input with `.` then the program shouldn't allow more than 2 inputs of `..` so that the user can just just go back with the arrow buttons and type in the correct input

```cpp
#include "examplevalidator.h"

ExampleValidator::ExampleValidator(QObject* parent)
    : QValidator (parent)
{
}

ExampleValidator::~ExampleValidator()
{
}

QValidator::State ExampleValidator::validate( QString & input, int & pos ) const
{
    if (input.isEmpty()) return Intermediate;
    bool ok;
    QString str;
    str = input[pos-1];

    if(input.size() == 10
            && ((input[2] == '.'))
            && ((input[5] == '.'))
            && input[0].isDigit()
            && input[1].isDigit() && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 31)
            && input[3].isDigit()
            && input[4].isDigit() && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 12)
            && input[6].isDigit()
            && input[7].isDigit()
            && input[8].isDigit()
            && input[9].isDigit() && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 2020)
//            && (pos == 1 )&& (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 3)
//            && (pos == 2 )&& (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 31)
            )
    return Acceptable;

    if(input.size() > 10)
    return Invalid;


    if((pos == 1 )&& (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 3) && input[0].isDigit())
    {return Intermediate;}

    if((pos == 2) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 31) && input[pos-1].isDigit())
    {return Intermediate;}

    if((pos == 3) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 1) && input[pos-1].isDigit())
    {return Intermediate;}

    if((pos == 4) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 1) && input[3].isDigit())
    {return Intermediate;}

    if((pos == 5) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 12) && input[4].isDigit())
    {return Intermediate;}

//    if((pos == 6) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 999999) && input[pos-1].isDigit())
//    {return Intermediate;}

    if((pos == 7) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 9) && input[6].isDigit())
    {return Intermediate;}

    if((pos == 8) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 99) && input[7].isDigit())
    {return Intermediate;}

    if((pos == 9) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 999) && input[8].isDigit())
    {return Intermediate;}

    if((pos == 10) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) < 99999) && input[9].isDigit())
    {return Intermediate;}

    if (input[0] == '.' )
    {return Intermediate;}

    if(pos > 1)
    {
        if (input.isEmpty()) return Intermediate;

        if((pos > 1) || (pos <=2 ) && (input[pos-1] == '.'))
        return Intermediate;

        if(pos > 8 && pos <= 10 && input[pos-1].isDigit())
        {return Intermediate;}
        else {return Invalid;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a simple pattern matching to validate `dd.mm.yyyy` first and then apply any range checking on the numbers. The code would be much more compact and easy to understand.

Comment: How do I do that? @Jean-MarcVolle

Comment: mistagged with `C`? Does not look like C at all ... tag removed

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to validate `dd.mm.yyyy`
Have a look at https://regex101.com/ for trying them out.
Something like the code below should get you started

```
#include <regex>

std::smatch match;
const std::regex ddmmyyyyRegExp(R"((([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})))");
std::string dd;
std::string mm;
std::string yyyy;
if (std::regex_search(input, match, ddmmyyyyRegExp) && match.size() == 4)
{
    dd= match.str(1);
    mm= match.str(2);
    yyyy= match.str(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to fix the code, but still I'm unable to check if the inputs are in a particular range. I'm trying to check if the date limit isn't more than 31 and month isn't greater than 12

````
ExampleValidator::ExampleValidator(QObject* parent)
    : QValidator (parent)
{

}

ExampleValidator::~ExampleValidator()
{

}

QValidator::State ExampleValidator::validate( QString & input, int & pos ) const
{
    if (input.isEmpty()) return Intermediate;
    bool ok;
    QString str;
    str = input[pos-1];

    if(pos > 0 && input[0] != '.')
    {
        if (input.isEmpty()) return Intermediate;

        if(((pos == 1 )&& (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 9) && input[0].isDigit() && input.size() != 10))
        {return Intermediate;}

        if(((pos == 2) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 99) && input[1].isDigit() && input.size() != 10))
        {return Intermediate;}

        if(((pos == 3) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 999)) && (input[2].isDigit() || input[2] == '.') && input.size() != 10)
        {return Intermediate;}

        if((pos == 4) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 9999) && input[3].isDigit() && input.size() != 10)
        {return Intermediate;}

        if((pos == 5) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 99999) && input[4].isDigit() && input.size() != 10)
        {return Intermediate;}

        if(((pos == 6) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 999999)) && (input[5].isDigit() || input[5] == '.') && input.size() != 10)
        {return Intermediate;}

        if((pos == 7) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 99999999) && input[6].isDigit() && input.size() != 10)
        {return Intermediate;}

        if((pos == 8) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 999999999) && input[7].isDigit() && input.size() != 10)
        {return Intermediate;}

        if((pos == 9) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) <= 999999999) && input[8].isDigit() && input.size() != 10)
        {return Intermediate;}

        if((pos == 10) && (input.toInt(&ok, 10) < 2020) && input[9].isDigit() && input[2] == '.' && input[5]=='.' )
        {
            return Acceptable;}
    }

    if(((pos == 1) && (input[0] == '.')) || ((pos == 2) && (input[1] == '.')))
    {
        return Intermediate;
    }
    else if (input.isEmpty()) {return Intermediate;}

}```
````